# Norm of Integral Operator on $E=\{u \in C[0,1]\ ,\ u(0) = 0\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, integral-operators

There are similar question but the characterization of the space $E$ that I have gives me problem in computing the actual norm.

Let $E=\{u \in C[0,1]\ ,\ u(0) = 0\}$ with the usual $\parallel \cdot\parallel_\infty$-norm.

Consider the linear functional $f$ defined as: $$f(u)=\int_0^1u(t)dt, \ \forall u\in E\ .$$
$\cdot$Show that  $f ∈E^⋆$ and compute $∥f∥_{E^⋆}$.

I can show that $f ∈E^⋆$ but I have troubles computing the actual norm of $f$.

$f ∈E^⋆$ iff $\ \ \ $ $f\ : \ E$ -> $\mathbb{R}$ and  $f$ is linear and continuous. Linearity follows easily from the properties of the integral. In order to show continuity, we show that $f$ is bounded since for linear operator boundedness is equivalent to continuity.

$|f(u)| = |\int_0^1 u(t)dt\ |\ \leq\ \int_0^1 |u(t)|dt\ \leq ||u||_\infty$, so taking the $\sup_{||u||\leq 1}$ we get that $||f||\leq 1$. Hence I would guess that: $$||f||=1$$
since we have that: $\forall u \in E, |f(u)|\leq||f||\cdot||u||_\infty$.

Now I should find some $u\in E$ such that $||u||_\infty = 1$ and $|f(u)|=1$ and the trick would be done, but I can *not* find such function.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to find $u\in E$ such that $|f(u)|/||u||_\infty=1$. It is enough to find a sequence $u_n$ such that $|f(u_n)|/||u_n||_\infty\to1$.

For this take the function(s) $u_n(x)=1$ for $x\geq1/n$ and $u_n(x)=nx$ for $x\in[0,1/n]$.

We can see that for this sequence

$$|f(u_n)|/||u_n||_{\infty}=|\int_{0}^{1}u_n(x)dx|\geq|\int_{1/n}^{1}u_n(x)dx|=1-\frac{1}{n}\to1.$$

Comment: isn't it a problem that $(u_n)$ converges to the function $g(x)=1$ which is *not* in $E$ ?

Comment: @Filippo No, we don't need to consider limit of $u_n$. What we are computing is $\sup_{u\in E}\frac{|f(u)|}{||u||_{\infty}}$. You already proved this supremum is at most $1$. So, one jsut need to provide a sequence such that the fraction in the supremum tends to $1$.