# Norm of Functional on : $c_0 = \{ x \in l^\infty :\ \lim_{k \to \infty}=0 \}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Take $E = c_0 = \{ x \in l^\infty :\ \lim_{k \to \infty}=0 \}$ and define on $E$ the functional:
$$F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{2^n}$$

$\cdot$Show that $F$ is a linear continuos functional on $E$and compute $||F||$.

Linearity is trivial. To show continuity we show boundedness.

$|F(x)|\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|x_n|}{2^n}\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{||x||_\infty}{2^n}= ||x||_\infty\cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}= ||x||_\infty$. Taking the sup for $||x||_\infty\leq 1$, yields $||F||\leq 1$.
So the guess is that $||F||=1$.

However I have now problems computing the actual norm of $F$. For $\forall x\in E$ we have that : $|F(x)|\leq ||F||\cdot||x||_\infty$, but I can *not* find a sequence $x$ to yield the desired result.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Note that the definition of $\|F\|$ contains a $\sup$, not a $\max$.  Equality does not have to be achieved by any particular $x$.  But here's a hint: consider a sequence  $x$ of which the first $n$ terms are 1 and the rest are 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to [a previous problem you posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104269/norm-of-integral-operator-on-e-u-in-c0-1-u0-0). It would be cool if we could take $\{x_n=1\}$ as the witness for the norm. But, $x_n$ doesn't tend to zero.

Instead we use a sequence of sequences $u_n$ such that $|F(u_n)|/||u_n||_{\infty}\to|||F|$. We can take $$u_n:=\{x_k=1\text{ for }n\leq n,\text{ and }x_k=0,\text{ for }k>n\}$$

Then $$\frac{|F(u_n)|}{||u_n||}=|F(u_n)|=\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^{-k}\to\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{-k}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

For $k\in\mathbb{N}$, take the cutoff sequence $x^k\in c_0$ defined by $x^k_j=1$ for $j\le k$ and $x^k_j=0$ for $j>k$. Now clearly $\Vert x^k\Vert=1$ and

$$|F(x^k)|=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{2^j}=1-2^{-k}$$

which tends to $1$. I don't think there's an $x\in c_0$ with $\Vert x\Vert=1$ and $|F(x)|=1$.