# Dual norm of a functional defined in $c_0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I'd like a check in the following exercise

> In $(c_0, \Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty}) $ consider for every element $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3,\ldots)$ in $c_0$ the functional $T(u)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}u_n$.
>
> Check that $T$ is a continuous linear functional and compute $\Vert T \Vert$ (the dual norm). Can one find some $u \in c_0$ s.t $\Vert u \Vert_{\infty}=1$ and $T(u)=\Vert T \Vert$ ?

---

The first part is clear and I'v checked it also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104402/norm-of-functional-on-c-0-x-in-l-infty-lim-k-to-infty-0). My problem is on how to formalize the last part: I strongly believe that there's no $u \in c_0$ with that property, but I don't know how to move properly.

From the boundedness one can see that $\Vert T \Vert \leq 1$, and choosing the "cut-off" sequence $u=(\underbrace{1,...,1}_{N \text{times}},0,0,\ldots)$ I have that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{u_{n}}{2^n}=1-2^{-N}$, and then the supremum over $N$ is 1, and than follows that  $\Vert T \Vert =1$.

But how can I say that there is no one $u$ with that property? I would say that the only way for which $T(u)$ is equal to $1 (=\Vert  T \Vert)$ is the cut-off sequence is made from all entries equal to $1$, which is a contradiction, since $u$ must belong to $c_0$. Is this enough?

Comment: What is $f(u)$?

Comment: Fixed, thanks !

Comment: Note that $T$ is defined and continuous with the same norm on $l_\infty$. If $\|x\| =1$ and $\|Tx\| = 1$ then we must have $|x_k| = 1$ for all $k$. Hence if $x \in c_0$ we must have $\|Tx\| < 1$.

Comment: @copper.hat I was looking for an explicit inequality, but thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you don't yet have a "proof" the idea is all there:

Suppose for contradiction that $T(u)=1$. Take any $\epsilon<1$. By definition of $c_0$ there is some $N$ such that $|u_n| < \epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.

Then $|T(u)| \leq \left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} + \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\right)| \frac{1}{2^n}u_n| \leq (1-2^{-N}) + \epsilon2^{-N}<1$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for a contradiction, and this makes the point.

Comment: Your proof uses, in the second inequality, also the fact that $\Vert u \Vert_{\infty}=1$, right? (and of course that $|u_n|<\epsilon $ for $n \geq N$)

Comment: Yes, first inequality is triangle inequality, second inequality is as you said.

Answer (score 1):

Since 
$ \Vert u\Vert_\infty = 1,$ we must have $|u_n|\leq 1$ for all $n$. 
Evidently, we cannot have $u_n = 1$ for all $n$, since in that case $u \not\in c_0$. Hence $|u_{n_0}| < 1$ for some $n_0$. Thus
$$ \left| \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{u_n}{2^n} \right| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|u_n|}{2^n} = \sum_{\substack{n\geq 1\\n\not=n_0}} \frac{|u_n|}{2^n}+\frac{|u_{n_0}|}{2^{n_0}} < \sum_{\substack{n\geq 1\\n\not=n_0}} \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^{n_0}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}=1, $$
for any $u \in c_0$, so in particular equality cannot hold since the inequality is strict.

Comment: It's quite clear, but I can't understand the second-last inequality: why does $\frac{1}{2^{n0}}$ disappear?

Comment: Ok, it's clear, you summed up for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, now I've seen ! Thanks